# how to add json module in Three20

Tags: iphone, three20

I tried to use command line to add Three20 with JSON :

python three20/src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p JsonTest/JsonTest.xcodeproj Three20 extThree20JSON:extThree20JSON+SBJSON

this command line successfully executed without any error message. I can find "extThree20JSON+SBJSON" in Direct dependencies and its link in linked libraries.

When I build my project with JSON import:
 #import "extThree20JSON/SBJSON.h"

xcode reported:  error: extThree20JSON/SBJSON.h: No such file or directory

help please:(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and just solved it.

1. Add the extThree20JSON.xcodeproj to your project by draging it in.
2. Add the extThree20JSON+SBJSON to the **Target Dependencies** in the
   Build Phases of your app's target.
3. Add the libextThree20JSON+SBJSON.a library to the **Link Binary With
   Libraries** in the Build Phases of your app's target.
4. Edit the **User Header Search Paths** in the **Build Settings** of
   your project, add the following paths:

   - ../three20/Build/Products/three20;
   - ../../frameworks/three20/Build/Products/three20;
   - ../frameworks/three20/Build/Products/three20;
   - $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../three20
   - $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../three20
5. Edit the **Other Linker Flags** in the **Build Settings** of your
   app's target, add the following flags:

   > -ObjC -all_load

More information on manually adding Three20: http://chepri.com/2011/04/22/visual-guide-manually-adding-three20-xcode-4-project/